# how does tcp connection works in kubernetes loadbalancer

Tags: kubernetes, tcp, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, tcpclient

Hi I am running 5 replicas tcp-client( can be scaled up) and exposed 3 services as LoadBalancer to external network to get incoming connection. This client is listining on a port 7777 internally and mapped to external port 17777, 27777, 37777.

Pods

```
[root@pwconfig-k8s-master0 tcp_poc]# kubectl get pods -l app=tcp-client
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
tcp-client-7dd545dcc9-54bdl   1/1     Running   0          4m47s
tcp-client-7dd545dcc9-628jn   1/1     Running   0          4m47s
tcp-client-7dd545dcc9-7pm44   1/1     Running   0          2m30s
tcp-client-7dd545dcc9-b287n   1/1     Running   0          4m47s
tcp-client-7dd545dcc9-mrmnm   1/1     Running   0          2m30s
```

Service

```
[root@pwconfig-k8s-master0 tcp_poc]# kubectl get svc | grep tcp-client
tcp-client        ClusterIP      y.y.y.y    <none>         7777/TCP                              4m36s
tcp-client-0      LoadBalancer   y.y.y.y   x.x.x.x   17777:30859/TCP                       2m55s
tcp-client-1      LoadBalancer   y.y.y.y     x.x.x.x   27777:30089/TCP                       2m55s
tcp-client-2      LoadBalancer   y.y.y.y    x.x.x.x   37777:31031/TCP                       2m55s
```

We have seen this behavior that once any external client makes the tcp connection, the connection get fixed with particular pod and stay alive until external client closes the connection. I wanted to know the how the routing  and tcp connection is working as I can see the LoadBalancing is over external client tcp connection not over the packets.
So if there are 100 external client , it will loadbalance over the client and route the tcp connection and fix with the pod for the lifecycle of the tcp connection.

Thanks for the help in advanced.

Comment: What is your environment, is it local or cloud one? Do you have any network limitations - firewalls, etc.?

Comment: it is local cluster

Comment: OK, thanks, could you possibly provide the k8s version and YAML manifests for the deployment and services?